# Widget not appearing in widget list

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I've read several questions about this on stackoverflow, and none of the answers are solving my problem.

I'm trying to add a home screen widget to my app, and my widget does not appear in Android's widget list.

**I've tried rebooting the device**, reinstalling the application, changing parameters in the configuration file, ensuring app is not installed on SD card.  Nothing is working.

Here is the code I currently have:

**Inside AndroidManifest.xml's application tag:**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".GulpWidgetProvider"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Gulp">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/gulp_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

**Inside /res/xml/gulp_widget_info.xml:**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/layout_widget"
    android:minHeight="150dip"
    android:minWidth="400dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:minResizeHeight="150dip"/>
```

**Inside /res/layout/layout_widget.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="170dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/widget_consumption_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
            android:secondaryProgress="100" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/widget_time_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2"
            android:secondaryProgress="100" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_water_consumed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_unit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/water_consumed"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/milliliters_abbrev"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_add"
            style="@style/GulpButton"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:background="@drawable/whitecirclebutton"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add_abbrev" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget_goal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/target"
                android:textColor="@color/white_semi_translucent"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget_remaining"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/remaining"
                android:textColor="@color/white_semi_translucent"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Inside /java/info/andrewdahm/gulp/GulpWidgetProvider.java:**

```
public class GulpWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_add, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why my widget isn't appearing on the list of widgets?

Comment: Try restarting phone

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I have already tried that.

Comment: Try using a fully qualified class name for android:name="GulpWidgetProvider" on the receiver xml?

Comment: @CSmith Are you suggesting prefixing GulpWidgetProvider with a period? Example:  `android:name=".GulpWidgetProvider"`.  I have just done this and the widget still does not appear in the list.

Comment: put the full path of the class, e.g. com.yourcompany.yourapp.gulp.GulpWidgetProvider.  This is just a guess, as it's how I've done this.

Comment: @CSmith Still no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an issue about the values you set in `gulp_widget_info.xml` for `android:minHeight` and `android:minWidth`.

Try to set a smaller values and the widget should appear in the launcher's widget list:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/layout_widget"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
    android:minWidth="40dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:resizeMode="none" />
```

I tested this settings in my phone with Google Now Launcher and it appears with size 1x1

The rule to calculate the size is `70 × n − 30` where *n* is the number of cells you want. You can find more information about how to determine the size of the widget [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size).

Comment: I swear I awarded the bounty when I first read it.  Stack just sent me an email reminding me to do so, so here it is!

Answer (score 2):

ACcording to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) link the Activity must be declared in the AppWidgetProviderInfo XML file, with the android:configure attribute and you are missing this.

Comment: This is only if you are creating a configuration Activity.